# Butterknife view in Fragment is null reference if call from parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife

i have problem with using [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) libray. There is I have SearchActivity.class use ViewPager with 3 Fragment in FragmentSearchAdapter:

**SearchActivity.class**

```
mAdapter = new FragmentSearchAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), SearchActivity.this);
    mAdapter.addFragment("search histori");
    mAdapter.addFragment("search query");
    mAdapter.addFragment("search result");
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int currentIndex) {
            if(currentIndex==2) {
                SearchResultFragment SearchResultFragment = (SearchResultFragment) mAdapter.getItem(2);

                if (SearchResultFragment != null) {
                    SearchResultFragment.setDescription("Text 1","Text 2");
                }
          }
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
    });
```

**FragmentSearchAdapter.class**

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                SearchHistoryFragment search_histori = new SearchHistoryFragment();
                return search_histori;
            case 1:
                SearchQueryFragment search_query = new SearchQueryFragment();
                return search_query;
            case 2:
                SearchResultFragment search_result =  new SearchResultFragment();
                return search_result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Where one fragment is **SearchResultFragment.Class**

```
public class SearchResultFragment extends Fragment {

    @Bind(R.id.text1)
    TextView text1;
    @Bind(R.id.text2)
    TextView text2;
    private String page_index;
    private PageAlquranActivity activity;

    public SearchResultFragment() {
    }

    public static SearchResultFragment newInstance(int page_index) {
        SearchResultFragment fragment = new SearchResultFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(Variabel.page_index, String.valueOf(page_index));
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            page_index = getArguments().getString(Variabel.page_index);
        }
        activity = (PageAlquranActivity) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        return v;
    }

    public void setDescription(String s1, String s2) {
        text1.setText(s1);
        text2.setText(s2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {super.onAttach(context);}

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

My Problem : when call method `SearchResultFragment.setDescription("Text 1","Text 2");` from SearchActivity, I get error :

> null object reference

each TextView. This error if use ButterKnife,but if not, it's work if I declare View like this :

```
text1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
```

in onCreateView.

so how to solve it ? Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `@Nullable` annotation just right before the `@Bind` ?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem (every injected view of a certain fragment becomes null after the page is changed). **Did you find any solution?**

Answer (score 1):

@AmayDiam you need to bind ButterKnife again in the called method. Pass along the dependency for the bind - the fragment view from the OnPageChangeListener

**SearchActivity.class**

```
mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
public void onPageSelected(int currentIndex) 
{
    if(currentIndex==2) 
    {
        SearchResultFragment SearchResultFragment = (SearchResultFragment) mAdapter.getItem(2);

        if (SearchResultFragment != null) 
        {
            SearchResultFragment.setDescription(mPager.getChildAt(currentIndex)"Text 1","Text 2");
        }
      }
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
});
```

**SearchResultFragment.Class**

```
public void setDescription(View view,String s1, String s2) 
{
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    //
    text1.setText(s1);
    text2.setText(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue too, just because I've added butterknife from Android Studio's Dependency management and not by copy-pasting gradle lines from Butterknife website.
So I had to add 

`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'`

instead of just

`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'`